# Integrate Mosquitto latest Library in Xcode

Tags: ios, mosquitto

I need to integrate Mosquitto library  to my iOS Project. As the library is in "C". I am getting lot of errors related to Compiler.

Can anyone suggest me how to integrate C code in iOS Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with Header search path and Library search path. As Mosquito library uses Openssl. You have to set Header search as well as Library search path to make it working.